# Arabic Character issue in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a php form that supports Arabic characters.But an issue here is characters entered in Arabic show "question marks" in mysql. I found out the issue is due to character Unicode and I fixed it.

How we can change the existing data to Arabic? Now it shows as "question marks". A Bulk set of users already registered.

Comment: set you database encoding to UTF-8 general CI

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: set the table / table field where you going to store the strings to utf8-general-ci

Comment: The question mark you're referring to is it an actual question mark "?" or the [replacement character �](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character)

Comment: GUYZ i need to change the existing characters to arabic , i fixed the newly inserted case.

Comment: If you have actual "?" characters stored in your database, you're already screwed; there's no way to fix those. If you are having *display problems* with data which is just stored in a messed up format but still recoverable, it depends on how it screwed up exactly. We need more details here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work out what character set the "?" are really stored then you may be able to use the php `iconv()` function.

The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Use the MySql `HEX()` function to find out what is really stored in the column.